# LocalDate.plusMonth giving incorrect result for February

Tags: java, date, java-8

I am trying to to use plusMonths API from java.time.LocalDate. Going through the java doc, its clear that the dates are adjusted for any invalid exceed of the dates.

For e.g 31-03-2017 + 1 Month = 31-04-2017--> 30-04-2017(as 31 April is invalid).

However, when I try to use the API for the February dates, it doesn't return the last day of next month(e.g March), instead returns the date after adding 30 days.

For e.g 28-02-2017 + 1 Month = 29-03-2017(expected 31-03-2017).

```
public class AddMonthTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2017, 02, 28).plusMonths(1));       
}
```

Gives output : 2017-03-28 where as expectation that it should return 31-03-2017.

Comment: why? Why do you think that?  It will adjust for any exceeds 28 does not exceed

Comment: But adding a month to 28th Feburary just makes it the 28th of March ... what adjust is required?

Comment: plusMonths function will not add 30 days as you mentioned, it will return the same date after number of months you mentioned.

Comment: So let's say I need to add one month at the end of feb, then do I need to take care programmatically? API won't help?? Even adding one month to "30-04-2017" would give "30-05-2017" (actually not month addition. isn't it?)

Comment: The API works as specified, so the question as worded should be closed. But if your real question is how to iterate over the last days in each month you should look at [TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastDayOfMonth--).

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Yes, API works as mentioned in java doc. I am not questioning, but my concern was about "plusMonth". Instead of "+1Month" its adding "30 days".

Comment: What do you mean it’s adding 30 days? In your example, 2017-03-28, only 28 days have been added. I suspect you’re mistaken there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth() move to the last day of month

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 28).plusMonths(1).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the doc would clearly specify that, I don't think it would do that. And it says:

> Returns a copy of this LocalDate with the specified number of months added

To me that is the same as **The result will have the same day of month as the incoming input** and this is what you see.